# Flutter - Execute/Run Facebook Pixel Code(Javascript code) on Flutter App

Tags: javascript, facebook, flutter, pixel

I need to run a Javascript code in my Flutter app. When user press one button i need to run this code:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '24023562411360');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=24035634111&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

It is possible?

Now i'm trying this from [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin), but i thinks isn't working:

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(
          "<!-- Facebook Pixel Code --><script>!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');fbq('init', '24022385634361');fbq('track', 'PageView');</script><noscript><img height='1' width='1' style='display:none'src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=24022385634361&ev=PageView&noscript=1'/></noscript><!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a javascript function from flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702938/calling-a-javascript-function-from-flutter-app)

Comment: I'm not familiar with these libraries, but maybe try removing the HTML tags around the JS code? i.e., remove `<!-- Facebook Pixel Code --><script>` and `</script><noscript><img height='1' width='1' style='display:none'src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=24022385634361&ev=PageView&noscript=1'/></noscript><!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are plugins currently available to call a js function. See examples from the following plugins:

- [flutter_js](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js)
- [js](https://pub.dev/packages/js)

Check out this blog ["JavaScript with Flutter | Is it possible?"](https://medium.com/@mustafatahirhussein/javascript-with-flutter-is-it-possible-c6ed53704c1b) to give you guide on implementation of js inside your Flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

To log events on Flutter Web, you firstly need to configure your Facebook Pixel inserting the snippet above `</head>` in `web/index.html`. You can find the snippet following this [guide](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755)

After that, you can send events to your pixel utilizing dart interoperability. More informations [here](https://dart.dev/interop/js-interop/usage)

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:js_interop_unsafe';
import 'dart:js_interop';

@JS()
external void fbq(String command, String eventName, JSAny? parameters);

class Tracking {
  static void sendEvent(
      {required String eventName, Map<String, dynamic>? parameters}) {
    //Meta Pixel
    try {
      final args = parameters?.jsify();
      fbq('trackCustom', eventName, args);
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```